# Why font face on WordPress is not working?

Tags: wordpress, font-face

This is the CSS code in my CSS file

```
    @font-face {
    font-family:'Raleway';
    src:url('fonts/Raleway-Regular.eot');
    src:url('fonts/Raleway-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/Raleway-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/Raleway-Regular.svg#font-name') format('svg');
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}


@font-face {
    font-family:'Arvo';
    src:url('fonts/Arvo-Regular.eot');
    src:url('fonts/Arvo-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/Arvo-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/Arvo-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/Arvo-Regular.svg#font-name') format('svg');
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}
```

The names of my Fonts are **Arvo-Regular.ttf** and **Raleway-Regular.otf**

I have uploaded the fonts in this path of my server.... (fonts folder)

**public_html/wp-content/themes/theme-name/fonts**

Still its not working.
What I am doing wrong?

**Will I have to rename Raleway-Regular.ttf to Raleway-Regular.otf** in
url('fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a proper path right now the path is undefined.

E.g:

```
 src:url('/wp-content/themes/theme-name/fonts/Raleway-Regular.eot');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your url from

```
src:url('fonts/Arvo-Regular.eot');
```

to

```
src: url('/fonts/Arvo-Regular.eot');
```

And check your font-path

Answer (score 0):

Check your permissions. I fixed it setting proper chmod on the font folder.